# SQL Server - select and join parent-child records, pivot and group

Tags: sql-server

The real problem is probably less complex than the subject might suggest.

**The schema**

Three tables (simplified).  There can be multiple people within one membership.  The main member is identified as `1` in `person_membership.relationship`, there can be a spouse of the main member identified as '2' and other dependants (any other number).

```
  CREATE TABLE person
      ([first_name] varchar(10), [surname] varchar(10), [date_of_birth] date, [person_id] int);

  INSERT INTO person
      ([first_name], [surname], [date_of_birth] ,[person_id])
  VALUES
      ('Alice', 'AA', '1/1/1990', 1),
      ('Bob'  , 'AA', '1/1/1990', 2),
      ('Carol', 'AA', '1/1/1990', 3),
      ('Dave' , 'AA', '1/1/1990', 4),
      ('Elen' , 'AA', '1/1/1990', 5),
      ('Fran' , 'BB', '1/1/1990', 6),
      ('Gaby' , 'BB', '1/1/1990', 7)

  CREATE TABLE person_membership
      ([person_id] int, [status_flag] varchar(1), [membership_id] int, [relationship] int);

  INSERT INTO person_membership
      ([person_id], [status_flag], [membership_id], [relationship])
  VALUES
      (1, 'A', 10, 1),
      (2, 'A', 10, 2),
      (3, 'A', 10, 3),
      (4, 'A', 10, 4),
      (5, 'A', 10, 4),
      (6, 'A', 20, 1),
      (7, 'A', 20, 3);

  CREATE TABLE memship
      ([membership_id] int, [memship_status] varchar(1));

  INSERT INTO memship
      ([membership_id], [memship_status])
  VALUES
      (10, 'A'),
      (20, 'A');
```

**The task**

Simplified version - display membership and person id of the main member and identify if they have a spouse, and also if they have any dependants show how many of them they are.

**The desired output**

The basic version something like the screenshot below.  Main member ID, their person ID, Yes/No field for spouse, number of dependants:
[image]

**The current solution**

The code below works and creates the desired output but it seems very clunky.  There must be more elegant ways of doing it?

```
    WITH peeps AS (SELECT person.person_id,
                          person.first_name,
                          person.surname,
                          person_membership.membership_id,
                          person_membership.relationship
                   FROM  memship, person, person_membership
                   WHERE person_membership.person_id = person.person_id 
                     AND memship.membership_id = person_membership.membership_id
                     AND person_membership.status_flag='A'
                     AND memship.memship_status='A')

    SELECT final.MemID, final.PersonID, sum(final.Spouse) as 'Spouse?', sum(final.Kids) as 'No of kids'
    FROM (
    SELECT
        peeps1.membership_id                 AS 'MemID',
        CASE peeps1.relationship
            WHEN 1 THEN peeps1.person_id
                    ELSE        peeps2.person_id
        END                                  AS 'PersonID',
        SUM (CASE WHEN
            peeps1.relationship = 2 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END )                                 AS 'Spouse',   
        SUM (CASE WHEN
            peeps1.relationship > 2 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END )                                 AS 'Kids'                             
    FROM peeps peeps1 
    INNER JOIN peeps peeps2 ON peeps2.membership_id = peeps1.membership_id AND peeps2.relationship = 1
    GROUP BY peeps1.membership_id, peeps1.relationship, peeps1.person_id, peeps2.person_id) as final
    GROUP BY final.MemID, final.PersonID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=df60bbac11892bddbcb12b1d0256d825)**

```
SELECT M.membership_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PM.relationship = 1 THEN P.person_id ELSE NULL END) person_id,
       SUM (CASE WHEN PM.relationship = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )AS 'Spouse',   
       SUM (CASE WHEN PM.relationship > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Kids'        
FROM  memship M 
JOIN person_membership PM ON  M.membership_id = PM.membership_id
JOIN person P ON PM.person_id = P.person_id 
WHERE PM.status_flag='A' AND M.memship_status='A' 
GROUP BY M.membership_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplified query

```
SELECT  MemID        = pm.membership_id,
        PersonID     = MAX (CASE WHEN pm.relationship = 1 THEN p.person_id END),
        [Spouce?]    = SUM (CASE WHEN pm.relationship = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [No of kids] = SUM (CASE WHEN pm.relationship NOT IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM    person p
        INNER JOIN person_membership pm ON  p.person_id         = pm.person_id
        INNER JOIN memship m            ON  pm.membership_id    = m.membership_id
WHERE   pm.status_flag      = 'A'
AND     m.memship_status    = 'A' 
GROUP BY pm.membership_id
```

Note : please avoid using old style of join. User `INNER JOIN` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT M.membership_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PM.relationship = 1 THEN P.person_id ELSE NULL END) person_id,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN PM.relationship = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )AS 'Spouse',   
       COUNT(CASE WHEN PM.relationship IN (3, 4, 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Kids'        
FROM  memship M 
JOIN person_membership PM ON  M.membership_id = PM.membership_id
JOIN person P ON PM.person_id = P.person_id 
WHERE PM.status_flag='A' AND M.memship_status='A' 
GROUP BY M.membership_id
```